# Export to CDF fails

Tags: differential-equations, cdf-format

The code below generates the error when I attempt to export to CDF Preview:

> Coordinate {xde[4.69588928222656], yde[4.69588928222656]} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.

Here is my code:

```
system = {x'[t] == 2 x[t] - 0.08 x[t] y[t], x[0] == 400,
   y'[t] == -y[t] + 0.01 x[t] y[t], y[0] == 25};

sol = NDSolve[system, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 6}];

{xde[t_], yde[t_]} = {x[t], y[t]} /. Flatten[sol];

Animate[Show[
  ParametricPlot[{xde[t], yde[t]}, {t, 0, 5.4}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"Prey", "Predator"}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 80}}], 
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{xde[t], yde[t]}]}]], {t, 0, 
  5.4, AppearanceElements -> "PlayPauseButton"}, AnimationRate -> 0.5]
```

How can this be fixed? Thx.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are just missing the `SaveDefinitions -> True` option in the `Animate` command.

Comment: You passed me in reputation: NOT ALLOWED!  :)

Comment: @rcollyer -- sorry, didn't mean to!